# How can i integrate smart contract with java application?

Tags: java, blockchain, smartcontracts

I wanna show proof to client wheteher the media is played or not whith in his scheduled time. Using java with smart contract and block chains, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to whether it is possible or feasible to do with blockchains.

But there are definitely simpler and more "standard alternatives". In digital ads, for example, advertisers often embed an ["impression pixel"](https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-tracking-pixel-work), which is just an invisible 1x1 image,  inside  the ad. Whenever a page with that ad gets displayed, a request is made for the pixel, so the advertiser knows it was displayed. There are also standards for viewable impressions, or video views etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check out the [Ethereum Contract API](https://github.com/adridadou/eth-contract-api) native in Java. The goal is to ease the integration of Ethereum in a Java project.

> - Easy configuration of the network and keypair use
> - Create an **interface for a smart contract**
> - Have type safety in regards of input and output values
> - Easy transaction creation
> - Easy synchronization when creating a transaction
> - Transaction creation returns Future, simple calls returns the value itself

On [youtube is a short presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWeNSvori4I&index=1&list=PLaM7G4Llrb7wPiT2G75tj2JQr8qg6P5hi) (15 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Why not develop a custom Java Client for your blockchain network ?

You may like to use Multichain for doing the same.

http://www.multichain.com/developers/